# How to search by member accessor value with std::find_if()?

Tags: c++, vector

I am learning C++ at the moment and have an example program implemented with an array of objects data store. To make some other operations easier, I have changed the store to a vector. With this change I am now not sure of the best way to search the store to find an object based on a member accessor value.

Initially I used a simple loop:

```
vector<Composer> composers; // where Composer has a member function get_last_name() that returns a string

Composer& Database::get_composer(string last_name)
{
    for (Composer& c : composers)
        if (c.get_last_name().compare(last_name))
            return c;

    throw std::out_of_range("Composer not found");
}
```

This works just fine of course, but to experiment I wanted to see if there were vector specific functions that could also do the job. So far I have settled on trying to use `find_if()` (if there is a better function, please suggest).

However, I am not sure exactly the correct way to use `find_if()`. Based on code seen in online research I have replaced the above with the following:

```
vector<Composer> composers; // where Composer has a member function get_last_name() that returns a string

Composer& Database::get_composer(string last_name)
{
    auto found = find_if(composers.begin(), composers.end(), 
                [last_name](Composer& c) -> bool {c.get_last_name().compare(last_name);});

    if (found == composers.end())
        throw out_of_range("Composer not found");
    else
        return *found;
}
```

This does not work. It does find a result, but it is the incorrect one. If an argument that matches, say the third composer's last name the function always returns the *first* item from the vector (if I pass an argument that doesn't match *any* last name the function correctly throws an exception)... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your question and problem, but IMO throwing an exception is maybe not the right choice here? Or is the use-case of not finding the name actually exceptional? And if it is, then it's not really *out of bounds* is it?

Comment: Your lambda is missing the return keyword.

Comment: In your case I would just stick with the range based for loop.  It is simple, easier to understand and is less code.

Comment: I can only second some programmer dude, there is nothing "out of range" here and not finding an element is also nothing exceptional

Comment: Probably remnants of Java programming, where everything under the sun that goes wrong is worthy of throwing an exception.

Comment: `compare` method returns `int` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare, I dont see how your other function "works just fine of course" if when composer names match it returns 0, thus going to the next name in the loop

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the interface was specified by the example I was working to; is there some other manner or idiom of indicating an error when the return type is a reference?

Comment: @Toby You got a point there. The only thing might be to return a sentinel object, similar to how the `end` iterator works. Especially if you're not allowed to change the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, your lambda needs return statement. Also in such case you do not have to specify it's return type explicitly, it can be deduced:

```
find_if(composers.begin(), composers.end(), 
            [last_name](const Composer& c) { return c.get_last_name() == last_name);});
```

you original code should not compile or at least emit warning(s), you should pay attention to them.

Note: it is not clear how your original code worked if you tested it, it should be:

```
if (c.get_last_name().compare(last_name) == 0 )
```

or simply:

```
if (c.get_last_name() == last_name )
```

as [`std::string::compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns `int` -1 0 or 1, so your code searches for string that does not match variable `last_name`

Answer (score 0):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may use *projection*:

```
auto it = ranges::find(composers, last_name, &composers::get_last_name);
```